# host name in local network Kodi media server installed on Ubuntu 21.04 desktop amd64

Tags: localhost

howto allow mobile devices connected to local network to open the Kodi media server with ip 192.168.0.2:8080 by typing media.tv or any name instead of entering the IP address

Comment: You can just use hostname.local sometimes, but the proper answer is to get a not-used domain name, and set your DNS server or hosts files to have that domain be the IP address of the Kodi server. You will also have to get Kodi to run on port 80 if you don’t want to have to specify the port. You might be able to reconfigure Kodi, or you could use NGINX to proxy port 80 to 8080

Comment: Thanks for answer, what I understood is set the router gateway to 192.168.0.2, second Kodi was unable to accept port 80 so how to proxy port 80 to 8080, finally is this valid for ubuntu desktop version also